# Make Custom OS For Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: operating-systems

I want to make my own OS for the Raspberry Pi B+. When doing my research I have came across [Baking Pi](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/).

The only issue with this is it only works with the Raspberry Pi model A (by the looks of the red note). Is there an up-to date tutorial on this? I cannot try this out at the moment since I do not have a USB keyboard.

Comment: I know that's not an exact duplicate -- Pi 2 vs. B+ -- but the principle is the same.  It should be fine, although you may want to check on specific address (either by digging online, or with specific questions).

Comment: So you mean the tutorial should mostly work except for some of the LEDs? So I would just need to change a few values? If I understand how to control the LEDs with assembly I should be able to fix it my self then?

Comment: Yeah.  I think other than the LEDs, everything on the + should be the same as the previous models, so the difference is less than between those and the 2.   Like I said, when you get to the part where hardware addresses are specified, you can ask about those here if you can't find the information elsewhere -- someone knows.  I'm sure they are generally identical since the same GPIO libraries are used on  the A/B/+ pis (but had to be tweaked for the 2), it is the same processor, etc.

Comment: I shall learn to control the GPIOs and LEDs using ASM first then go to the tutorial. This should help me. Thanks. As always if I need help I shall ask here.